Resource of Cost of Declaring Variables and Scope
I'm at the beginning of my journey learning C#, I'm mid-way through the Microsoft Learn syllabus. I recently encountered a lesson where they stated it's best for security and resource management to give variables as little scope as possible. I wanted to know whether repeated declaring a variable has an impact on resources used by the system. For example:
Code 1:
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while (i < 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Sublist");
    while (j < 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Entry: {j}");
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}

vs
Code 2:
int i = 0;

while (i < 10)
{
    int j = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Sublist");
    while (j < 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Entry: {j}");
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}

Thanks in advance for any and all responses.

Forget about security and resource management and think about cognitive load. If you narrowly scope your variables then there's less information to think about. This becomes increasingly important over time, especially when multiple people are working on the code.

Jim (comments) is right that cognitive load is a more important factor here. Splitting large methods into smaller methods can help greatly.
When talking about local variables inside a method, we need to be clear about two different things:

overhead of the variable
overhead of the lifetime an object reached by a variable

The problem is: the compiler and runtime/GC are smart, so usually these are only real factors in niche cases.
In terms of overhead of the variable: usually, this is a non-issue, as the variable will occupy the same local declaration in the IL regardless of our "declaration scopes" that only exist in the weak human meatsack world. But there are exceptions:

if a variable is "captured" into a delegate/lambda or similar, the scope is pivotal in defining the capture-context used by the delegate, which can have an impact on allocations but also correctness (for with lambdas is a huge cause of bugs)
stackalloc space, if moved inside a loop, usually unnecessarily, can burn through stack space at a frightening rate (stackalloc is very rare in most code!)

When talking about object lifetimes: the GC can see if you don't read from a local again, so if you've read the local for the last time, the scope doesn't matter (again: declaration scopes only exist in meatsack space). However! If there are lifetime concepts like using in play, this does matter, and changing it changes the behaviour - this can be for better or for worse, and only you know what the lifetime should be.
Side note: I think it is a stretch to say that there is a genuine security angle here.

Thank you this answers my question perfectly!

Your examples would run endlessly without incrementing, but in terms of scoping variables there are two main reasons to restrict scope. Firstly, memory usage, garbage collection, and releasing system resources. Though that is more of a concern for variables that reserve a significant amount of memory, or could tie up resources like database connections etc. The second reason is to avoid situations where a variable might be referenced outside of its expected scope. The value may not be accurate or even left in a valid state.  In many cases for things like counters there are structures that embed the variables into the loop scope itself. For instance instead of while(i < 10) and ensuring "i" is incremented properly, you would use for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) This scopes "i" to the for loop logic, and handles the incrementing cleanly.
The compiler will build IL to execute the code functionality you write which will often have optimizations for reusing variable allocations. For raw performance declaring a variable once would be faster, though the compiler may end up optimizing the code to a point where that doesn't make a notable difference. Writing good code is a balancing act between performance and writing easy to understand source that avoids places for bugs to hide.
The most important instances to scope correctly are any references that are disposable. (Implement IDisposable or extend a class that implements it) These are scoped using the using keyword. For instance:
using (var reader = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    // read from reader..
}

FileStream is Disposable so this ensures that when you are done reading via the reader instance, that instance is disposed, file handles released, etc. If you don't dispose of that instance, if you had code later on that tried to delete the file, that operation would fail as a handle is still open. With C#8 you can also use using to mark the instance to be disposed at the end of the current scope. (Method scope, or within an if block, etc. via:
using var reader = File.OpenReader(path);

Instead of creating a scope, it adopts the scope the variable was declared in.

Thanks for the response. Apologies for the error in the code, I was rushing to think of an example. I'll update the code now. This response was very helpful!
